# Is there any way to map dictionary of type [NSString: Any] to another [String: Any]

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimage, nsstring, foundation

I tried to cast dictionary of type **[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]** to **[String: Any]** type, but it seems it's not possible. The result was nil. I've found straightway to iterate throught original dict, grab value and insert it with rawValue. But maybe I'm doing it wrong

debugger showed that **[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]** under the hood is **[NSString: Any]**

```
let imagePropsDict: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any] = getStubbedProps()
var propsDict: [String: Any] = [:]
imagePropsDict.forEach { infoKey, value in
    propsDict[infoKey.rawValue] = value
}
```

and the invalid code:

```
if let mappedDict = imagePropsDict as? [String: Any] { ... }
```

Comment: In Objective-C, it's a NSDictionary which keys are `NSString`, but in Swift, `imagePropsDict` isn't. `InfoKeys` is a struct (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey), with `String` raw values. You What's your goal exactly?

Comment: @Larme my exact goal was to map [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any] to [String: Any]

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this conversion? And what's wrong with your `forEach` approach? It looks like it should work.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah it works, i just thought there's more elegant way ;)

Comment: See [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/mapping-dictionary-keys/15342) for a variety of ways.